# Allow Concurrent Booking without Overbooking

Tags: performance, jpa, database-design, concurrency

I have an appointment booking system, which involves 2 steps:

1. User selects a date which has available slot (where `total_booked < quota` and `quota` could be more than 1)
2. Users provides other info (name, contact etc) and submit the
   booking. If successful, `++total_booked` in slot and create a new row
   in appointment table.

It is not like a typical cinema booking or airline booking system, where a seat can be booked only one. If quota is 10, the system should allow 10 persons to book concurrently (but only reject person 11 and above)

FYI, I am using JPA (Hibernate), PostgreSQL with isolation read committed and prefer no native query. Few methods I had tried:

- I can't use Optimistic Lock, for case quota more than 1, where the system throws `StaleObjectStateException` as long as multiple users book at the same time.
- I have created a `constraint check` (`total_booked <= quota`), but
  it can't prevent the overbook issue as the `++total_booked` does
  not increase the count correctly (the isolation is read committed) when there is more than 1 user access step #1 at the same time. In other word, the number of appointments sometimes is more than the value of `total_booked`.
- I may not consider to change the isolation level to `Serializable`
  as it may slow down the performance.

The system is up and has existing data. Any good solution for my problem?

Comment: No.  You've eliminated all the steps I can think of to make your transactions atomic.

Comment: You will simply have to lock the slot using `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE`, I don't think there's any other way in your scenario